# Using JavaScript to execute command line calls

Tags: javascript, jsp, maven

I want to execute a maven command (mvn test) from javascript code but it doesn't work here's the code of my Servlet ;

```
 out.println("<script type='text/javascript'> " +
      "function f(){ try{var wsh = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'); " +
      "wsh.Run('cd C:/Users/Amira/junoWorkspace/TestProjectUI');" +
      "wsh.Run('mvn -Dtest=MyClassTest test') } catch(err){} } </script> "); 

 out.println("<body><input type='submit' value='Execute Test' onclick='f()'>  </body>");
```

So any idea please 
if there's a better solution please mention it 
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that.
Ever​​​​​​.

Comment: *Forever ever?* Forever ever. `:P`

Comment: @SLaks can i do it with java? do you have any other solution

Comment: @AmiraManai: You will never be able to execute commands on the client machine.

Comment: Uhm, it may be possible with ActiveX. In IE, that is.